# Why to use Phonegap if you only develop on one platform

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I've been checking out a lot of open source projects for a SQLite map database I'm getting ready to develop and have seen a lot of finished Phonegap applications that are just primarily written natively for one platform with an index that just have references. Why do I see this so much? What the advantage to this?

Comment: The only advantage is future enhancement for other platform. If there is no need for other platform I would suggest to go native app.

Comment: creating apps using web languages is also faster than going native

Answer (score 1):

1. If you don't know the language+the sdk&apis you need to know to build native apps
2. If you think maybe oneday you will have to target an other platform
3. if you want to use some libraries available in javascript
4. if you want to share code between your app and a webapp

Ok, there are also many disvantage as speed or the need to test with many devices because you rely on the webview. If the target is android maybe using crosswalk can remove many of the disadvantages.

Comment: 5. If you already know HTML/CSS/JS, it's easiest to just build an app with Cordova, no matter how many or few the platforms you use.